# Unterminted #ifndef while using SDL in dev c++

Tags: c++, sdl

i am currently having problem rectifying this error in my dev c++ project, here is my code:

```
#ifndef GRAPHICS_H
#define GRAPHICS_H

struct SDL_Window;
struct SDL_Renderer;

class Graphics {
public:
    Graphics();
    ~Graphics();
private:
    SDL_Window* _window;
    SDL_Renderer* _renderer;
};
```

But the compiler says "unterminated #ifndef" and expected initializer before '~' token, i have tried to fix this problem for more than 3 hours but still couldn't fix this.

Comment: You forgot to add `#endif` at the end

Comment: If you just enter that error in Google you get an explanation in one of the first results. If you really spent 3 hours on this, don't focus on working more, focus on working more effectively.

Comment: You should add `#endif` in the file. However, that does not explain the other error. It will be good if you can post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#ifndef GRAPHICS_H
#define GRAPHICS_H
```

`#ifndef` statements need to be closed by an `#endif`. You should probably add it to the end of your file so you keep everything in it within the scope of GRAPHICS_H.

Comment: thanks, that really worked  but in my "graphics.cpp" file, in the code Graphics::Graphics()~Graphics() {
 SDL_DestroyWindow(this->_window);
} , it showed expected initializer before '~' token can you help me with this?

Comment: @user2891869 if you have another question you should ask another question.

Comment: try `Graphics::~Graphics() { SDL_DestroyWindow(this->_window); }`.

Comment: @user2891869 If this answered your question then please mark the answer as such.